# Resetting a Lumia 640 to Windows 8.1

Tags: 8.1, lumia, windows-10-mobile, reset, lumia-640

I want to reset my Lumia 640 to 8.1 in order to get wifi calling. But I have two questions about that:

1. Will Windows Update automatically update to Windows 10 whenever I
   update the phone, or will it just update to the latest 8.1 build?
2. My phone was bought as an AT&T phone and they then gave me the
   unlock code. Will I need to unlock it again? If so - Will the
   original unlock code that they gave me work again, or is it a
   one-time code and I'll have to hope they'll give me a new code
   again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will Windows Update automatically update to Windows 10 whenever I
>   update the phone, or will it just update to the latest 8.1 build?

There is no automatic updates from WP8.1 to W10M. You must install the [Upgrade Advisor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/upgrade-advisor/9nblggh0f5g4) tool to upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile.

Just don't install the Upgrade Advisor. Turn ON automatic updates. You will receive updates for 8.1(if any) without installing Windows 10.

> My phone was bought as an AT&T phone and they then gave me the unlock
>   code. Will I need to unlock it again?

No need. Carrier unlocking is a one time process.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't seem like what the Upgrade Advisor is for.

Comment: @ispiro I am 100% sure of my answer. In other words, **You cannot upgrade to Windows 10 Mobile without installing Upgrade advisor.**

Answer (score 2):

The unlock process is a one-time operation.  Once the phone is unlocked, it will remain unlocked.

Once you update the phone to Windows 8.1, simply turn off automatic updates since it is highly unlikely any Windows 8.1 Mobile updates will be released in future.

I believe Windows Device Recovery Tool will automatically download the latest Windows Mobile 8.1 build to your device.

Comment: Thanks. But I do want it to update from its factory settings to the most recent update of 8.1, so I will need to update. Is there a way to update up to (but not including) Windows 10?